# Web data extraction and data mining; Scraping vs Injection and how to get data.. like yesterday

Tags: screen-scraping, scrapy, code-injection

I feel like i should almost give a friggin synopsis to this/these lengthy question(s)..

I apologize if all of these questions have been answered specifically in a previous question/answer post, but I have been unable to locate any that specifically addresses all of the following queries.

This question involves data extraction from the web (ie web scraping, data mining etc). I have spent almost a year doing research into these fields and how it can be applied to a certain industry. I have also familiarized myself with php and mysql/myphpmyadmin.

In a nutshell I am looking for a way to extract information from a site (probably several gigs worth) as fast and efficiently as possible. I have tried web scraping programs like scrapy and webharvey. I have also experimented with programs like HTTrack. All have their strengths and weaknesses. I have found that webharvey works pretty good yet it has its limitations when scraping images that are stored in gallery widgets. Also I find that many of the sites I am extracting from use other methods to make mining data a pain. It would take months to extract the data using webharvey. Which I can't complain given that I'd be extracting millions of rows worth of data exported in csv format into excel. But again, images and certain ajax widgets throw the program off when trying to extract image files.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Are there any quicker ways to extract said data?
2. Is there any way to get around the webharvey image limitations (ie only being able to extract one image within a gallery widget / not being able to follow sub-page links on sites that embed their crap funny and try to get cute with coding)?
3. Are their any ways to bypass site search form parameters that limit the number of search results (ie obtaining all business listings within an entire state instead of being limited to a county per search form restrictions)**

Also, this is public information so therefore it cannot be copyrighted; anybody can take it :) (case in point: Feist Publications v. Rural Telephone Service). Extracting information is extracting information. Its legal to extract as long as we are talking facts/public information.

So with that said, **wouldn't the most efficient method (grey area here) of extracting this "public" information (assuming vulnerabilities existed), be through the use of sql injection?... If one was so inclined? :)**

As a side question just how effective is Tor at obscuring ones IP address? Lol

Any help, feedback, suggestions or criticism would be greatly appreciated. I am by no means an expert in any of the above mentioned fields. I am just a motivated individual with a growing interest in programming and automation who has a lot of crazy ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off writing your own Linux command-line scraping program using either a headless browser library like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (JavaScript), or a test framework like [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) (Java).

Once you have your scrape program completed, you can then scale it up by installing it on a cloud server (e.g. Amazon EC2, Linode, Google Compute Engine or Microsoft Azure) and duplicating the server image to as many are required.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I will definitely look into these! I haven't been on in awhile so sorry for the late response.

Comment: @Singularity20XX No worries, I run a scraping program myself on a single Linode server ... its using the Selenium Webdriver (jar package) and a Java mainline (multi-threaded). Has been rock solid for several months now, scraping fares from airline websites. It was the only solution I found that worked after trying several libraries.